# Is there a way to make the code runner not close the external terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I don't know how to explain it, but I will try.

So I write C++ code and I run it with code runner. But the program closes itself. I don't want to use `system("PAUSE");` because I need to remove it if I'm in a competition.

So is there another way?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522206/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson nope this doesn't work.  I was asking about that when you open an external terminal with the extension to not close itself (the external terminal) right after the code has been runned.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried something that came to my mind and it works.

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "g++ $fullFileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && start cmd /k $fileNameWithoutExt.exe"
}
```

I used this in the settings.json

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dev C++ as an alternative IDE. But if you wish to do it in Visual Studio without a system("PAUSE"); you can use cin.get(); or cin.ignore(); as an alternative.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    cin.ignore();
}
```

or

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    cin.get();
}
```